# Any scholarly views about how someone like Ovidius might have pronounced Greek words?

Tags: pronunciation, ancient-greek, phonology, ovidius

Μετᾰμορφώσεις

In this word, as can be seen, there is a pitch accent on ω, and also it is generally accepted (per Allen, *Vox Graeca*) that φ was an aspirated P (pʰ), not a fricative (f).

Are there any views about how educated Latins like Ovidius might have pronounced Greek? When speaking his verse, would he have said [pʰaɪtʰɔn] or [faɪtɔn] for Phaethon?

Comment: This may be useful for you, even though there were no references pertaining to his claims other than the pun Catullus made: https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/7do69p/how_did_romans_really_pronounce_greek_sounds/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of thing I was hoping to hear about. Both Greek- and Latin-speakers seem to have written quite a bit about both languages, pronunciation, etc.

Comment: Happy to be of help!